# Expression denotes a `value', where a `type' or `method group' was expected in calling StartCoroutine inside a thread in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this class.

```
public class UploadData: MonoBehaviour{
    public void uploadindividualshot(pushdatawrapper pw){       
        StartCoroutine (PushData (pw));
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartCoroutine(PushData(pw))));
        t.Start();
        t.IsBackground = true;
    }

    private IEnumerator PushData(pushdatawrapper pdata){
        WWW www;
        Hashtable postHeader = new Hashtable();
        postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        string dataToJason = JsonUtility.ToJson(pdata);
        Debug.Log ("dataToJason " + dataToJason);
        // convert json string to byte
        var formData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToJason);
        www = new WWW("http://rmotion.rapsodo.com/api/push/new", formData, postHeader);

        return www;

    }
    IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW data)
    {
        yield return data; // Wait until the download is done
        if (data.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("There was an error sending request: " + data.text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Request: " + data.text);
        }
    }

}
```

I got error at `Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartCoroutine(PushData(pw))));` as Expression denotes a `value', where a`type' or `method group' was expected.

How can solve that issue?

Comment: Share the definition for `Startcoroutine`.

Comment: You do **not** need a Thread to download data with the `WWW` API. This API is already threaded. You just use coroutine to wait for it until the request is done. Note that even if you get this code to compile, you will get a run-time error that says you can't use blah blah blah from another Thread. Just a warning.

Comment: As for your error, it is because ThreadStart ctor takes a delegate and you are passing a new object. But it is not required here since WWW will be on its own thread. But it won't work anyway as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget what you want to do even if you get rid of you error another error you will be thrown as soon as your Coroutine start that's because Unity is thread safe you can not use Unity specific API outside of the main thread (Except vectors if don't mistaken). You have 2 choices.

1. use just a Coroutine without threads.
2. use thread but avoid Unity API by using WebClient class for example

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write

```
Thread t = new Thread(obj => { PushData(obj); });
```

PushData is the method group. `PushData(pw)` is the actual method call. You can [should] pass data to your thread proc like `t.Start(pw);`

Side note: `t.IsBackground = true;` should be set before `t.Start()` call.

Comment: I have error at `Thread t = new Thread(obj => { PushData(obj); });` as `Delegate `System.Threading.ThreadStart' does not take `1' arguments`

Comment: I do not think this is the whole story. The code I wrote compiles just fine. Alternatively, you can try to change `PushData` to `void PushData(pushdatawrapper pdata)` and then do `new Thread(PushData)` directly.